# Find MAX value from declared values (variables)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three values and I have to find `MAX` value from these values

Example:

```
DECLARE @r int=10
DECLARE @s int=15
DECLARE @t int=50

SELECT MAX(@r, @s, @t)
```

I have to find 50 like this

Comment: A temp table would solve it `declare @tmpTable table (value integer)`, insert your values to temp table and select `max(value)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a code like this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (a INTEGER)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES(3)

SELECT MAX(a) FROM @temp
```

You can't run `MAX` on more variables. `MAX()` takes only 1 parameter, the column name in a table.

But, if you have to use the variables, then:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(col1 INTEGER)

DECLARE @r int=10
DECLARE @s int=15
DECLARE @t int=50

INSERT INTO @temp(col1) values(@r)
INSERT INTO @temp(col1) values(@s)
INSERT INTO @temp(col1) values(@t)

SELECT MAX(col1) FROM @temp
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you have found an answer that works best for you, then to mark that answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @r int=10,  @s int=15, @t int=50

SELECT max(val)
  from (values(@r),(@s),(@t)) X(val)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not waste resources with temporary table solutions.

Just make an union of all those variables.

[**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14024)

```
DECLARE @r int=10

DECLARE @s int=15

DECLARE @t int=50

SELECT max(t.value)
  from (select @r as value
        union
        select @s as value
        union
        select @t as value) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(v)
    FROM (
       SELECT 1 as v UNION
       SELECT 2 as v UNION
       SELECT 3 as v
     ) t
```